# Missing functions for NVIDIA CUDA 12.3 CSR Formatted Sparse Linear Algebra

Tags: c++, cuda, nvcc

Does anyone know why the cuSPARSE documentation for CUDA version 12 references `cusparseDcsrsv2_analysis` and `cusparseDcsrsv2_solve`, but these functions are no where to be found in their actual `cusparse.h` library?

Their CUDA version 10 does indeed have the functions in `cusparse.h`.  It seems like all types and functions that are of `CSR` and `SV` (hence "csrsv") are gone in version 12.

I already submitted a ticket to NVIDIA, but I would like to know a work-around.  Are there any equivalent functions for CSR formatted matrix to vector multiplication functions in cuSPARSE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cuSparse has a new [generic API](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html#generic-api-functions) including [`cusparseSpSV()`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html#cusparsespsv) and [`cusparseSpMV()`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html#cusparsespmv) (OP mentions "matrix to vector multiplication" which is "mv", not "sv"). Generic means that there is a wrapper `cusparseSpMatDescr_t` which can describe many different sparse matrix formats including [CSR](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html#id2). This way the name/interface of the functions like `cusparseSpSV()` is independent of the sparse format which makes it easier to build on the cuSparse API when writing generic APIs oneself.

The fact that `cusparseDcsrsv2_analysis()` is still mentioned in the documentation (found it in the example [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html?highlight=cusparseDcsrsv2_analysis#cusparse-t-csrilu02-deprecated)) seems to be an oversight on Nvidia's side and was rightfully reported by OP.

See cuSparse's [Library Organization and Features](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html#library-organization-and-features) for a description of the generic API. Note also how these features where [marked as "deprecated" in CUDA 11](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/11.8.0/cusparse/index.html#csrsv2_analysis), so their disappearance in CUDA 12 should not be a surprise. This is also what the [CUDA 12.0 release notes](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html#cusparse-release-12-0) allude to.